# Getting embedded code of a post via Crowdtangle API

Tags: api, embed, embedded-resource

I have a special question working with the Crowdtangle API: Does anybody know, if it is possible to fetch the embedded code of a post via GET/posts Syntax? Or is it generally restricted? In addition I have the same question for getting comments of a special post. Didn't find any solutions or workarounds by doing that. And of course I read the documentation. Maybe somebody can give input :-)

Comment: Hey! George from CrowdTangle here. Are you looking for the embed code so you could embed a post on a webpage, for instance?

Comment: As for your other question, comments are not available via the CrowdTangle API, but if you are a Facebook developer, you can request comments from the Facebook GraphAPI here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/object/comments

Comment: thx for answering me George :-) I am just playing around and want to know which kind of data I can fetch with CT API, so I didn't find information in the documentation about the embed code and comments and was just asking if there is a way I didn't saw